# iOS Swift Parse-Server user login authentication

Tags: node.js, swift, mongodb, parse-server

I have spent the last few days migrating my humble parse and swift app over to Heroku and MongoDBLab.

However, I seem to have an issue with login authentication with just the parse server running on Heroku but not the MongoDBlab server. I say this because the version of the app that is routed through Parse.com and then to MongoDB is able to login, reset password, and create a new user. However, the app version routed through Heroku and then to MongoDBLab will not authenticate the user, but will allow a new user to be created.

The Heroku server was set up using the git [Parse-server-example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example)! procedure.

I'm using PFLogInViewController and PFSignUpViewController to handle the view.

I have seen some other posts concerning Facebook logins, but I can't see how they might relate, but I am also tired.

The login return prompts that the login failed, please try again later.
The forgot password return prompts that the path is not implemented when attempting to email the user.

My initial thought is that the parse-server on Heroku needs additional code to handle authentication and password reset. Being this is my first node.js and mongoDB service, I would imagine I'm missing a few things to boot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answers to the authentication issue.

The [git for parse-server Issue #32](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/32)

Evidently the first migration DB tool had some issues? Specifically in the mongoDB _SCHEME_SESSION where expiresAt was defined as date instead of string.